# How to get input from another file for my Sudoku game C using a .txt file

Tags: c++, cin, sudoku

Alright so my problem is that I have no idea where to go in my situation with my Sudoku Program. As of right now I have multiple programs that work together to create my Sudoku program which is SUPPOSED to take input of 9 lines with 9 characters each whether it be just spaces or numbers.
example:

```
53  7    
6  195   
 98    6
8   6   3
4  8 3  1
7   2   6
 6    28
   419  5
    8   79
```

What the program would yield would be:

```
534678912
672195348
198342567
859761423
426853791
713924856
961537284
287419635
345286179
```

My current programs consist of the files stack.h, stack.cc, sudokuboard.h sudokuboard.cc, sudoku.cc, and Makefile, as well as test.txt(consists the example of input i had above)

the programs stack.h:

```
struct Node {
  StackElementType data;
  Node *next;
};
class Stack {
 public:

 Stack(); //constructor
 ~Stack(); //deconstructor
 Stack(const Stack & orig); // copy constructor
 void output(ostream & ostr) const; //output method
 bool empty() const; // if empty returns true
 void push(const StackElementType & item); // puts new item on top of stack
 void pop(); // removes top element of nonempty stack
 StackElementType top() const; // returns copy of top element of a stack

 private:
 Node*first;
 size_t _size;
}
```

Note that there may be misspellings in this due to having to being unable to copy my code directly so most of this is freshly typed out.

My stack.cc is

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

void destroy(Node *p)
{
  // delete all nodes dominated by p.
  while (p != NULL) {
    Node *old = p;
    p = p->next;
    delete old;
  }
}

Node *copy(Node *p)
{
  // Make a deep copy of linked list dominated by p.
  Node *result = NULL;
  if (p != NULL) {
    result = new Node;
    Node *last = result;
    while (p != NULL) {
      // invariant: last points to a node ready to receive p's data.
      last->data = p->data;
      last->next = NULL;
      p = p->next;
      if (p != NULL) {
    // there's going to more to this copy.  Get it ready.
    last->next = new Node;
    last = last->next;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

Stack::Stack()
{
  first = NULL;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
  destroy(first);
}

Stack::Stack(const Stack & orig)
{
  first = copy(orig.first);
}

Stack & Stack::operator=(const Stack & rhs)
{
  if (this != &rhs) 
    first = copy(rhs.first);
  return *this;
}

void Stack::output(ostream & ostr) const
{
  ostr << "<";
  for(Node *p = first;p;p=p->next) {
    ostr << p->data;
    if (p->next)
      ostr << ", ";
  }
  ostr << ">";
}

void Stack::push(const ElementType & item)
{
  Node *born = new Node;
  born->data = item;
  born->next = first;
  first = born;
}

void Stack::pop()
{
  assert(!empty());
  Node *rest = first->next;
  delete first;
  first = rest;
}

ElementType Stack::top() const
{
  assert(!empty());
  return first->data;
}

bool Stack::empty() const
{
  return first==NULL;
}
```

So this is simply what I am using for my stack

My sudokuboard.h:

```
#include <iostream>

#define SDIM 9

class SudokuBoard {
 public:
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  SudokuBoard();
  // Construct a blank sudoku board
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void print(std::ostream & ostr) const;
  // display it.  duh.
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void place(size_t r, size_t c, char digit);
  // PRE: safe(r,c,digit)
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void remove(size_t r, size_t c, char digit); 
  // PRE: get(r,c) == digit
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  char get(size_t r, size_t c) const;
  // Return the digit at (r,c) on the board.  or ' ' if blank.
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  bool safe(size_t r, size_t c, char digit) const;
  // 
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------

  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  bool done() const; 
  // Return true iff every cell has a number
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
 private:
  std::string rows[SDIM];
};
```

While my sudokuboard.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "sudokuboard.h"

#define ASSERTBOUNDS assert(0 <= r and r < SDIM and 0 <= c and c < SDIM)

SudokuBoard::SudokuBoard()
{
  for (size_t i = 0;i<SDIM;i++) {
    rows[i] = "";
    for (size_t j=0;j<SDIM;j++)
      rows[i] += ' ';
  }
}

void SudokuBoard::place(size_t r, size_t c, char digit)
{
  ASSERTBOUNDS;
  assert(safe(r,c,digit));
}

void SudokuBoard::remove(size_t r, size_t c, char digit)
{
  ASSERTBOUNDS;
  assert(get(r,c)==digit);
  rows[r][c] = ' ';
}

char SudokuBoard::get(size_t r, size_t c) const
{
  ASSERTBOUNDS;
  return rows[r][c];
}


void SudokuBoard::print(std::ostream & ostr) const
{
  for (size_t i=0;i<SDIM;i++)
    ostr << rows[i] << std::endl;
}
bool SudokuBoard::safe(size_t r, size_t c, char digit) const
{
 for(size_t r=0; r<SDIM; r++)
    for(size_t c=0; c<SDIM; c++)
       if (get(r,c) == digit)
           return false;

 for(size_t c=0; c<SDIM; c++)
    for(size_t r=0; r<SDIM; r++)
       if (get(r,c) == digit)
           return false;
  return true;
}
bool SudokuBoard::done() const
{
  for (size_t r=0;r<SDIM;r++)
    for (size_t c=0;c<SDIM;c++)
      if (rows[r][c]==' ')
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

My sudoku.cc right now is pretty much blank because I have only a general idea on how to pursue my goal. The way I am going to fill in the empty spaces is that I am going to take to take a single area and put in the smallest possible number in its current row/column and if there is a higher number in its row/column is goes up +1. I then go down the column and so on.

My question is how do i integrate the following programs of sudokuboard.cc and stack.cc in my sudoku.cc. I know I have to get the input of test.txt some how and convert each of the lines to the empty board, but I don't know how to phrase the cin input for that at all!

In other words I am looking for any help to get my sudok.cc started and how should I approach it?

sudoku.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "sudokuboard.h"
#include "stack.h"

int main()
{


}
```

I just want to say thank you who gave me these answers, now my lab is well on its way thanks to you guys! I cannot give any of you points b/c my rep is too low but otherwise i would!

Comment: You can still accept the answer that you chose to go with, so that your post will not appear as "unanswered" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I would use to read the text file:

```
//Code here
std::ifstream infile("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
if(infile.is_open())
{
    char szFileData[32]; //I think we can assume that each line won't be above 32 bytes
    infile.getline(szFileData, 32);
    do
    {
       //Set the cells to the data you just pulled
       infile.getline(szFileData, 32);
    }while(infile.good());
}
else
{
   std::cout<<"Unable to open file!"<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So that opens the code, but how would i assign each character on each line to = part of my 9 arrays for row[r][c] so I can call upon it it to change the numbers to complete the sudoku program.

Comment: That would determine on what kind of delimiter you use. For example, you could feed the C Function strtok the szFileData variable, and then pass a space as the delimiter. Then take the string returned from strtok and see if it's a number. If it's a number place it in the array (wherever it needs to be). A counter per while iteration could give you all the rows, considering each call to getline should return all the columns. If you need more clarification let me know, I'm running out of characters to give the rest of the insight

Comment: Just to be clear because I have never the commands "std" "ifstream" "infile" "getline", "szFileData" do I have to define any of these are all of these already defined in iostream?

Comment: @keyerer The are not all defined in iostream. Browse [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus.com/) to see more infos about each of them. `std::` is a namespace, it englobes _standard_ functionality of c++. If you want to get rid of it, add `using namespace std;` at the top of your file (after includes for example)

Comment: ah thank you very much for all of this information man, you have been very helpful

Comment: std is the namespace.
`ifstream` is an object you get when you `#include <fstream>`
With it coupled with `#include<cstdlib>` you get identifier`.getline`.
`infile` is a object of type `std::ifstream` and `szFileData` is something you declare yourself, I chose to do it with a char array of 32.

Comment: Why do you think that no line has more than 32 characters?  You can never make such assumptions concerning external input.

Comment: And if the file is missing the last `'\n'` (often the case for text files under Windows), you're code will skip the last line (in practice---in fact, it's not really specified what will happen).  Testing for `infile.good()` is always an error.

Comment: And finally, of course, he wants exactly 9 lines.  Not however many happen to be in the file.

Comment: @James Kanze: generally I never make a size assumption, however I have never heard of a basic soduku puzzle being over 9 numbers wide. Ergo, 32 bytes to find the \n char is almost overkill in his particular situation.

Comment: @ James Kanze: lastly, if the file is missing the \n its not an impossible fix, and as for utilizing infile.good, assuming there's a newline at the end, it would pull null, and good would no longer be true. Lastly, I quick wrote this to give the guy an idea, I'm not going to optimize and code the entire thing for him. I want him to think and fiddle with it, not give him something to c&p and not learn from.

Comment: @M4rc You're reading external text.  You've never heard of a line longer than 32 characters.  You're assuming the text is correctly formatted before having read it.

Comment: @M4rc With regards to using `infile.good()`, it's simply an error, since `good()` doesn't provide meaningful information in this case.  The use of `ios_base::good` is almost always a sign that the author doesn't really understand iostream.

Answer (score 0):

To read in a file, look at [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/). You can read from a file stream as you would from std::cin.
You could then read the whole file and store it in a `std::vector<std::string>` or something else, it's up to you. Find the container that suits you the most to use.

```
std::vector<std::string>  data;
std::string               line;
std::fstream              file("test.txt", std::in);

if (file.good())
{
   while (file.eof() == false)
   {
     getline(file, line);
     data.push_back(line);
   }
}
```

You can then access the data by doing `data[r][c]`.
I can't test it right now so there may be some slight errors, but it's the general idea

Comment: Could you give me a couple lines of solid code for if I wanted to get those 9 lines of numbers and apply with with sudokuboard program that would fit into my soduko.cc?

Comment: Do i put this in my int main() part or outside of it and just to make sure I am supposed to use vectors right?

Comment: You can put it wherever it suits you, but the main would be a good place to parse the file and then call your algorithm. You could create a function that returns you the `std::vector` created from the file to keep the main a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why you even have a `Stack` class.  You have a
stack for free if you use a recursive function.

With regards to your question: I'd use `std::getline` to read the lines.
Whether you ignore characters beyond the 9th, to allow comments, or
whether you treat them as a format error on input is up to you.  From
experience, however, I'd at least allow additional trailing whitespace.
Once you have the line, the easiest solution is probably to force it up
to a minimum of 9 characters (function `resize` on the string), adding
trailing blanks.  I'd then check that all of the characters are either
digits or the space character (`std::find_if`, with an appropriate
predicate).  It might also be simpler if you converted spaces into '0':
if your internal representation uses `0` for an empty square (the most
logical choice, IMHO), you can then simply subtrace `'0'` from each
character and assign it to the appropriate square.

Assuming the most logical representation of the board (`vector<int>`), this
would give something like:

```
struct TransformInputForSudoku
{
    int operator()( char ch ) const
    {
        if ( ch == ' ' ) {
            return 0;
        } else if ( ! isdigit( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) ) ) {
            return ch - '0';
        } else {
            throw std::runtime_error( "Illegal character" ) ;
        }
    }
};

std::vector<int>
getBoard( std::istream& source )
{
    std::vector<int> results;
    while ( results.size() < 81 ) {
        std::string line;
        if ( ! std::getline( source, line ) ) {
            throw std::runtime_error( "Input error" );
        }
        line.resize( 9, ' ' );  //  extra char's are comments
        std::transform( line.begin(),
                        line.end(),
                        std::back_inserter( results ),
                        TransformInputForSudoku() );
    }
    return results;
}
```

(This code combines input validation and conversion in a single
functional object.)

Comment: I just want to say thank you who gave me these answers, now my lab is well on its way thanks to you guys! I cannot give any of you points b/c my rep is too low but otherwise i would!